# How to create an Installer for a Delphi Project with Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, windows, delphi, installation, package

My problem is the next:

I have a recently finished project on Delphi 7 (Yes i know it's old). The project manages data form a Database created in Mysql 5.0 and uses MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1 to link the data.

I need to distribute the software but i have seen necessary the creation of an installer... That's the problem...

How i can create an installer that makes all the process of Installing Mysql 5.0, ODBC, Run the database on local computer, create the ODBC data origins (On windows) and finally Install my Application.

I don't know if i'm getting complicated...

Thanks.

Comment: BTW Is it an open source project or did you paid oracle for the license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).
Great Installer and Freeware.

In additions if you search on Internet, you can find several Inno Script for different purposes.
Here, for example, you can find  script for "Installing MySQL ODBC Connector with app" ([link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?535673-RESOLVED-Deploying-Installing-MySQL-ODBC-Connector-with-app)).

Regards.

Comment: MySQL ODBC Connector comes packed in an MSI installer. I would not *install* those libraries manually as your linked solution does. I bet you'll be able to find an example even on StackOverflow.